# Pass continue param to MWAPI inside Wikidata query

Tags: sparql, wikidata, mediawiki-api, wikidata-api

Is it possible to pass the `continue` parameter to a MWAPI call inside a Wikidata SPARQL query?

For instance, I have this query which uses the MWAPI EntitySearch and that always returns at most 50 results. I want to be able to set `continue` hoping that I can get n result sets, each containing max. 50 entities:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
 SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";
   wikibase:api "EntitySearch";
   mwapi:search "York"; 
   mwapi:language "en".
   ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
 }  
 SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The API does multiple queries to the MWAPI using the continue mechanism by default, so you don’t have to do anything, theoretically.

The two parameters you can twiddle are

```
bd:serviceParam wikibase:limit 10 .
```

…which sets the size of each call to the API,  it won’t change much because it will just make more/less calls, and…

```
bd:serviceParam wikibase:limit "once" .
```

…which disables continuation.

To start fetching from somewhere in the middle, sort by QID or some other value from the data and add FILTER(?qid > y) as appropriate.

Comment: from my understanding, he was asking this because the `limit` parameter does not work as one would expect when writing `bd:serviceParam wikibase:limit 100 .` - it does always return at most `50`, in the [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI) a max of 10000 rows is mentioned, but that might be just for Wikidata SPARQL in general. So how do you get more than 50 results for EntitySearch via MWAPI and SPARQL is the question?

Comment: If the "API does multiple queries to the MWAPI using the continue mechanism by default", I assume that MWAPI EntitySearch has a hard limit of 50 and doesn't offer / respond to `continue`?

Comment: `action=wbsearchentities` supports `continue`. However, there seems to be no automatic continuation for the MWAPI EntitySearch inside of a Wikidata SPARQL query, judging from the behavior.